# Openlayers - ArcGIS Vector tiles - OFFSET

Tags: openlayers, arcgis, vector-tiles

We have created a web application using Openlayers- showing primarily ArcGIS REST data using the ImageArcGISRest source.

We would like to be able to show some Vector tile data at the same time - but are having some problems with the tiling scheme and or extent.
The vector tiles, which have been created in ArcGIS Pro, are EPSG:25832 - the same projection as the ImageArcGISRest source.

When viewing the vector tiles and ImageArcGISRest in the same Openlayers map - the vector tiles are offset by 10.000 meters horizontally.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

I have created a simple fiddle to show the code and the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/larssoe/0vyw2Lg5/150/

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:25832', "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");
    ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var myProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:25832');
myProjection.setExtent([130000, 5661139.2, 1378291.2, 6500000]);  
var resturl = 'https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Plandistrikter2/MapServer';

const mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
  projection: 'EPSG:25832',
  className: 'custom-mouse-position',
  target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([mousePositionControl]),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 10,
        projection: myProjection
    //projection: 'EPSG:25832',
  }),
  layers: [
    
    new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      //tilegrid: myTileGrid,
      projection: 'EPSG:25832',
      minZoom: 0,
      maxZoom: 15,
      maxResolution: 1638.4,
      wrapX: false,
      url: 'https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf'
      }),
      tileSize: 512,
      //tilegrid: myTileGrid2
    }),
  new ol.layer.Tile({
        title:'ArcGISRest',
        source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
            url: resturl,
            params: {
                FORMAT: "png32",
                LAYERS: "show:0",
                DPI: 96
            },
            projection: ol.proj.get("EPSG:25832"),
      //tilegrid: myTileGrid
        })
    })
  ],
});

map.on('moveend', move);

function move(event) {
    var info = document.getElementById('info');
  const extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
  const resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  const zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
  info.innerText = 'zoom: ' + zoom + ' resolution: ' + resolution + ' extent:' + extent;
  info.style.opacity = 1;}

var info = document.getElementById('info');
function showInfo(event) {
  var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
  if (features.length == 0) {
    info.innerText = '';
    info.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }
  var properties = features[0].getProperties();
  info.innerText = JSON.stringify(properties, null, 2);
  info.style.opacity = 1;
}

var center = [706000,6216062];
map.getView().setCenter(center);
map.getView().setZoom(6);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The origin of the vector tiles shown in https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer is  X: 120000.0 Y: 6500000.0 so the tilegrid, which is based on the projection extent is too far east.  If you correct the extent both layers will work as TileArcGISRest will work with any extent.

Answer (score 1):

To others with vector tiles offset problems:
The initial offset problems (both horizontal and vertical) where solved by setting the property **maxResolution**. In my case to 1638.4